# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded - can't find recursion

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, recursion

Chrome throws this error every 1 in 20 or so times I load the page. I've gone through the code - bear in mind this was more or less the first time I used jQuery for anything - couldn't find an obvious source of the problem. I understand it's likely a recursion. The fact the error doesn't throw on every page load is making it that bit more difficult to debug. A few more pairs of eyes taking a quick look would be a great help.

Go easy, I know some of this code is janky:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // viewport fix for iOS
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/)) {
        $('meta[name="viewport"]').remove();
        $('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1">').appendTo('head');
    }

    //imgx retina image swap
    $(function() {
        $('.image').imgx(); 
    });

    // animate loader
    function animateLoader() {
        $('#loader').animate({ 'opacity' : '0' },400, function() {
            $('#loader').animate({ 'opacity' : '1' },0, function() {
                animateLoader();
            });
        });
    }
    animateLoader();

    // hamburger toggle class
    $('.hamburger').click(function() {
        $('.hamburger').toggleClass('is-active');
        $('#nav').slideToggle(200);
    });

    // set on state if active
    $('.linkhome.active span.pre').css({ 'width' : '10px' });

    // nav hover
    $('#nav ul li').hover(function() {
        $(this).children('span.post').animate({ width : '10px' }, 100);
    },function() {
        $(this).children('span.post').animate({ width : '0' }, 100);
    });

    $('#nav ul li, section div a').click(function() {
        if (!$(this).is('.active')) {

            // hide mobile nav on click and scroll to top
            if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 992px)').matches) {
                $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 400, 'swing' );
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('.hamburger').toggleClass('is-active');
                    $('#nav').slideToggle(200); // delay allows band and scrollTop animations to complete
                }, 400);
            }

            if ($(this).is('.linkhome')) { var sectionColor = '#60cfc7'; } 
            else if ($(this).is('.linkplans')) { var sectionColor = '#49bbcc'; }
            else if ($(this).is('.linknetwork')) { var sectionColor = '#6ca3ab'; }
            else if ($(this).is('.linkguarantees')) { var sectionColor = '#a8f4ff'; }
            else if ($(this).is('.linkcontact')) { var sectionColor = '#fff'; }

            var linkId = '.' + $(this).attr('class');
            var sectionId = '#' + $(this).attr('class').replace('link', '');

            $('#band').animate({
                'height' : $(sectionId).height(),
                'background-color' : sectionColor
            }, 400);

            var positionWords = 0;
            $(sectionId).prevAll().each(function() {
                positionWords += parseInt($(this).outerHeight() - 1, 10); // -1 to compensate for jQuery margin collapse bug
            });
            $('#words').animate({
                'margin-top': -( positionWords )
            },400);

            $('#nav ul li' + linkId).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
            $(linkId).children('span.pre').animate({ width : '10px' }, 100);
            $(linkId).siblings().children('span.pre').animate({ width : '0' }, 100);
            if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 1000px)').matches) {
                $(linkId).children('span.post').animate({ width : '0' }, 0);
            } else {
                $(linkId).children('span.post').animate({ width : '0' }, 100);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    // animate buy plan arrow
    $('ul.plan li.planBuy').hover(function() {
        $(this).children('span').stop().animate({ left : '5px' }, 100);
    },function() {
        $(this).children('span').stop().animate({ left : '0' }, 100);
    });

    // buy plan urls
    $('#buyBronze').click(function(){
        goog_report_conversion('/clients/cart.php?a=add&pid=1');
        window.location = '/clients/cart.php?a=add&pid=1';
    });
    $('#buySilver').click(function(){ 
        goog_report_conversion('/clients/cart.php?a=add&pid=2');
        window.location = '/clients/cart.php?a=add&pid=2';
    });
    $('#buyGold').click(function(){ 
        goog_report_conversion('/clients/cart.php?a=add&pid=3');
        window.location = '/clients/cart.php?a=add&pid=3';
    });
});

// position content on load
$(window).on('load', function(){
    $('#band').animate({ 'height' : $('#home').height(), 'background-color' : '#60cfc7' });
    $('#words').animate({ 'margin-top' : -$('#preload').height() - 1 }); // -1 to compensate for jQuery margin collapse bug
});

// re-position content on resize
$(window).resize(function() {   
    var sectionId = '#' + $('#nav ul li').closest('.active').attr('class').replace(/link|active/g, '');

    var positionWords = 0;
    $(sectionId).prevAll().each(function() {
        positionWords += parseInt($(this).outerHeight() - 1, 10); // -1 to compensate for jQuery margin collapse bug
    });
    $('#words').css({ 'margin-top': -( positionWords ) });
    $('#band').css({ 'height' : $( sectionId ).height() });         
});
```

Comment: `animateLoader` ?

Comment: Cheers Daniel, not sure how I overlooked that. Now looking into a way to loop animation without recursion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// animate loader
    function animateLoader() {
        $('#loader').animate({ 'opacity' : '0' },400, function() {
            $('#loader').animate({ 'opacity' : '1' },0, function() {
                animateLoader();
            });
        });
    }
    animateLoader();
```

In your code this function will be call as recursion so that reason you can get maximum call stack error. try to comment this function than check is error can come or not

Comment: Yep, 100 refreshes later and no error. So how to loop animation without recursion? setInterval perhaps, I'll get Googling...

Comment: Yes you can try setInterval its may works as you accept

Answer (score 0):

As stated earlier by Jay, the problem is in recursion in your `animateLoader()` function.
If you want to hide your loader only once after page has loaded - your can do it with css animation:

CSS:

```
#loader {
    /* Your loader style */
    animation: hide 0.4s 1;
}
@keyframes hide {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

If you want to show and hide loader whenever you want, you can do it with css transition and tiny bit of js:

CSS:

```
#loader {
    /* Your loader style */
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.4s;
}
#loader.hidden {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    hideLoader();
});

function hideLoader() {
    $('#loader').addClass('hidden');
}

function showLoader() {
    $('#loader').removeClass('hidden');
}
```